# Access: Runtime error 3075 (missing operator) in SQL update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

First time using Access and wanted to make an update query that uses a variable for its table name. Now, I've gotten myself into a web of nothing good. When I get to the part the SQL code is needed for, I get `Runtime error 3075 - Missing operator in '(((" + enteredid + ".todayDate)=Format(Now()','""Short Date"")))'` I've never coded in SQL, so I have no clue what operators are needed.

My code:
`strSQL = "UPDATE " + enteredid + " SET " + enteredid + ".signIn = Format(Now(),""Short Time"") WHERE (((" + enteredid + ".todayDate)=Format(Now()','""Short Date"")));"`

Comment: You've got some random apostrophes in the last 'Format' function - see what happens without them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions:

1. You can avoid the whole `Format()` issue in the WHERE clause by using the `Date()` function instead of trying to extract just the date part of `Now()`.
2. Since you are doing an UPDATE on a single table you can just use the field (column) names without the `TableName.` prefix.
3. To make your code more robust, enclose the table name in square brackets so it won't crash if the table name contains spaces or other "funny" characters.

So, the revised code would look more like this:

```vbs
strSQL = _
        "UPDATE [" + enteredid + "] SET " + _
            "signIn = Format(Now(),""Short Time"") " + _
        "WHERE todayDate = Date()"
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions.  Since Gandalf is new to Access, he should learn how to inspect the `UPDATE` statement his code builds.  `Debug.Print strSQL` would help. After running the code, Ctrl+g to view the statement text in the Immediate window.  For troubleshooting, he can copy that statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new query.

Comment: Actually, the code that I was using was from a regular update query that I put into SQL View and copied. Weird how it didn't work...